# Get All tables allowed to user with jdbc

Tags: java, database, jdbc

I'm connecting to a database using jdbc, getting list of all schemas and tables from database (I assume that some databases may return at this point only tables which current user can query, but some of databases return full list of tables) and when user try to query some tables he get "insufficient privileges" error. 
Is there a way to get only tables, user can query using only jdbc capabilities? Without writing special query to database.

Now I'm looking at

```
      DatabaseMetaData dbMeta = connection.getMetaData() 
      dbMeta.getTablePrivileges(null, null, null);
```

But from result of this query it's not so clear which exactly tables can user query.

Currently I'm working with SAP HANA database, but in general it may be any database, so I'm looking for some common approach.

Comment: what output do you get and what is unclear about it?

Comment: Please look at Ashraff Ali Wahab post and my comment. I have result set as described in documentation, and it's not clear for me does this result set relate to user I'm querying or this is list of all tables in DB?

Answer (score 1):

Please look at

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getTablePrivileges%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29

You have to get the each row from the ResultSet and query of column name TABLE_NAME which contains the table name and PRIVILEGE which contains the access of each table.

Comment: Does all this privileges relates to user, with who's  credentials I'm making query or this is a list of all tables in database and list of all who can query them?

Comment: If I take all tables, which have "select" privilege I then get "insufficient privileges" error.  I tried to select tables where grantee column equals current user name or public. but there is still left some tables which are not selected, but user can query them.

Comment: Interesting. Have you looked at the javadoc.